# Why is data returned from django.contrib.postgres.fields.JSONField a string?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, python-3.x

Environment:

- Django 1.9.10
- psycopg2 2.6.2
- PostgreSQL 9.5.4 installed via Homebrew on macOS Sierra
- Python 3.5.2 installed via Homebrew

Example model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField


class Foo(models.Model):
    data = JSONField()
```

When I try to create an object, everything works as expected:

```
from myapp.models import Foo
x = Foo()
x.data = {'some key': 'some value'}
x.save()
```

However, when I try to retrieve that data, the value of the `.data` attribute is a string:

```
from myapp.models import Foo
x = Foo.objects.order_by('-id')[0]
# returns "{'some key': 'some value'}"
x.data
# returns <class 'str'>
type(x.data)
```

My question: how do I get back the `dict` so I can manipulate data within the JSON field?

**EDIT**: Using `json.loads()` fails because the property names and values are enclosed in single quotes rather than double quotes:

```
import json
json.loads(x.data)
# JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

I can use `eval()`, but that's obviously extremely dangerous.

Comment: Surely you would use `json.loads()` rather than eval.

Comment: You could do use `json.loads()` to turn that string into the dict you want, but that's very odd. I have an application which uses `JSONField` and this does not happen. Also, if that was the expected behaviour, there wouldn't be much difference between using `JSONField` or `TextField` for example. Are you sure the object you are retrieving is exactly the same that you saved with `x.data = {'some key': 'some value'}`?

Comment: @lucasnadalutti the table was empty before I ran this example, so it's guaranteed to be the right object because it's the _only_ object.

Also, see the latest edit for why `json.loads()` isn't working.

Comment: As lucas says, this shouldn't happen. Are you sure the data you originally passed was really a dict, not a string?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I think you're right.  I think Django-rest-framework is screwing me up. Let me try something...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the custom DRF serializer I had written to create this field (spawning from actions taken by a POST to another model's `detail_route`) was using DRF's `CharField` rather than `JSONField`.  Whoops!